# How to make margin fill the rest of the available div?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
     <img style={{width:'10px', marginRight:'20px'}}/>
</div>
```

I do NOT have access to the div. Basically what I need to do is have the left margin autofill to the rest of the parent div, but I do not have access to the parent div. For example, if the parent div is 100px, I need the marginLeft to be 70px. If the parent div is 40px, I need the marginLeft to be 10px. This seems so simple but I can't find any css to do this. Ideally, I would like a marginLeft:'fillRemainingSpaceInContainer' argument.

Comment: text-align:right on the parent

Comment: display:block to the image + margin-left:auto;

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left: auto` will work. Set the `display` to `flex`

```css
div {
  background: lightpink;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="" style="width: 10px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: auto; display: flex; height: 10px; border: 1px solid">
</div>
```

The `height` and `border` are so that you can visualize the image. And assume the CSS portion is not controlled by you. All you need to do is enter the remaining styles for the img

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not have access to the parent div, and therefore I can't set the display to flex.

Comment: @AlbertHoffman You don't need to. I've set it to the img tag. Done nothing to the parent

Answer (score 0):

You can do a CSS rule called "calc" for this. It works like this:

```
<div>
  <img src="https://www.zocalopublicsquare.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Davidson_LEAD.jpg" 
  width="10" 
  height="7" 
  style="width: 10px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: calc(100% - 30px);"/>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bfmt2ghk/

Answer (score -1):

You are tripping.

All you want is to display an image on the right? To do that you need this

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.parent img {
    width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```